# Looping Until A File Exists

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, loops

Ok, the following codes shows how I am enterting a value into a textbox, adding that value to the listbox, updating a picturebox next to it and blanking out the textbox so the user can add additional values to the listbox.

```
    ListBox1.Items.Add(TextBoxTicketID.Text)

    If CStr(ListBox1.Items(0)) = TextBoxTicketID.Text Then
        PictureBoxStatus1.Image = My.Resources.Orange_Information
    End If

    TextBoxTicketID.Text = ""
```

I have another process not shown here that will create a PDF based on the value that was entered into the listbox.

I'm having trouble with a loop to check a specific directory if the PDF exists or not. When the PDF exists, I'll change the picturebox to another image.

Here is the loop that I was using, but the issue I ran into was that the user couldn't enter a second value unless the first value was present.

```
Loop Until My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists("c:\Temp\" + ListBox1.Items(0) + ".pdf")
PictureBoxStatus1.Image = My.Resources.Green_Checkmark
```

So in theory, I need to be able to enter X amount of values into the listbox and keep checking to see if the file exists and if it does, change those images that needed.

**EDIT**

Here's what I ended up doing...seems to be working fine though...

```
    ListBox1.Items.Add(TextBoxTicketID.Text)

    If CStr(ListBox1.Items(0)) = TextBoxTicketID.Text Then
        PictureBoxStatus1.Image = My.Resources.Orange_Information
    End If

    TextBoxTicketID.Text = ""
    Call CheckFiles()
```

Added a public sub

```
    Public Sub CheckSpooling()
    Dim Watcher As New FileSystemWatcher()
    Watcher.Path = "C:\Temp\"
    Watcher.Filter = ListBox1.Items(0) + ".pdf"

    AddHandler Watcher.Created, AddressOf OnChanged

    Watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = True
    End Sub
```

Then the sub to run whatever is needed if the file was added. I used a msgbox for testing.

```
    Private Shared Sub OnChanged(source As Object, e As FileSystemEventArgs)
    ' Specify what is done when a file is created.
    MsgBox("File has been created!")
    End Sub
```

Comment: Have you considered using [threads](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/315577)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the [FileSystemWatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx)

Comment: If I have an additional question to piggy back off your suggested answer, should I submit a new question? I'd hate to make my original post longer...or just add an additional edit section?

Comment: I would start a new question.  Your new question can contain a link to this question if the detail is relevent.

Answer (score 1):

The reason the user can't enter anything while you are looping is because the `WinForm` framework is essentially single threaded.  Everything in the UI occurs on the same thread, including the event handler.  So, if you are sitting in a loop for a long time in a button click event handler, then the UI will be locked up and unresponsive until the code exits the loop.  The way to get around this is to start a new thread to perform whatever work needs to be done.  That worker thread can take as long as it needs to complete and it won't interfere with the UI thread so the UI remains responsive.  This is made easier by the `BackgroundWorker` component which you can drop onto your forms in the form designer.

However, the `FileSystemWatcher`, as Dan-o has recommended is probably a better solution than creating your own worker thread that keeps checking if the file exists.  Not only does it avoid re-inventing the wheel, but it also will be more efficient.  Instead of constantly asking the file system if a file exists, it just listens to messages from the file system to find out when changes occur.